# How to display count in group header in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

```
I have a crystal report in C# windows application.
```

Three groups are there in the report.
I need to display count for each group.
For Eg:

```
 1.  Group1.1
      1. Group2.1
         1. Group3.1
              1.ItemDetails1
              2.ItemDetails2
         2. Group3.2
              1.ItemDetails3
              2.ItemDetails4
      2. Group 2.2
          1. Group3.3
              1.ItemDetails5
              2.ItemDetails6
          2. Group3.4
              1.ItemDetails7
              2.ItemDetails8
   2.Group1.2
```

like this?
I tried running total,
 Field To Summarize as Group1 field,
 Type as distinct count
 Evaluate- for each record
 Reset- On change of group 
but its showing 1 everywhere.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Try Never Reset. When you reset using the field that you count, you will always get an answer of one.